# How to get id(address) of each value in list in python like pointer C?

Tags: python

First of all, I'm not good at English, sorry.

I'm trying to get id of list in python, to make each variable get filtered value by locale function.

Please check out the code below.

```
dayLow ="123124"
dayHigh = "200000"
volume = "21512542"
marketCap = "235136346137"

toLocale = [dayLow, dayHigh, volume, marketCap]

afterLocale = list()

def locale(inform_data):
     inform_data = f"{inform_data:,}"
     return inform_data

for item in toLocale:
     item = locale(int(item))
     afterLocale.append(item)

i = 0
while(i < afterLocale):
    id(toLocale[i]) = afterLocale[i]
    i += 1
```

and it's not working, and spit error out like that.

```
    File "c:\******\test.py", line 19
    id(toLocale[i]) = afterLocale[i]
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

So the question is

How can each variable in toLocale(dayLow, dayHigh, ...) gets the value filtered by function locale()?

Comment: `id(toLocale) = afterLocale[i]` what is this line supposed to be doing?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I missed to indexing. I just edited it to id(toLocale[i]).

Comment: Even with that it doesn't make any sense. What __do you want to happen when that line executes?__

Comment: For example, dayLow has value like "123124", and this will go to locale function. locale function makes "123124" to "123,124". and I thought this code makes assignment "dayLow = "123,124". and it's not working. I just want to make assignment like that.

Comment: Why not just do `dayLow = locale(dayLow)` ?

Comment: because I'm making my project for web page by flask. And there is so many variables(dayLow, dayHigh ...) I can't handle it... I cut it to easy question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign to a variable by using it's `id()` - that's not what `id()` is for.

If you want to dynamically assign variables to values, you can use `exec` to do so.

But **I WOULD HIGHLY RECOMMEND NOT DOING SO**. 
Just type out the extra code required. It'll save you a lot of headache in the long run

```
dayLow ="123124"
dayHigh = "200000"
volume = "21512542"
marketCap = "235136346137"

toLocale = {'dayLow': dayLow, 'dayHigh': dayHigh, 'volume': volume, 'marketCap': marketCap}

def locale(inform_data):
     inform_data = f"{inform_data:,}"
     return inform_data

for var_name, var_value in toLocale.items():
     exec(f'{var_name} = "{locale(int(var_value))}"')

print(dayLow, dayHigh, volume, marketCap)
```

Output:

```
123,124   200,000   21,512,542   235,136,346,137
```

Comment: OMG, Thank you for this answer with warning!! while(1): "THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what exactly you want, but if you are trying to translate the values, using a dictionary would be maybe better for your usecase:

```
items = {
    "dayLow": 123124,
    "dayHigh" 200000,
    "volume": 21512542,
    "marketCap": 235136346137,
}


# now you can use `locale` for the keys:
for name, value in items.values():
    # `name` will have a value of "dayLow", "dayHigh" etc...
    print(locale(name), value)
```